# How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties excluding undefined or null properties

Tags: javascript, clone, helper

I can have different version of an object:

```
myObject1 = { 
  color: 'red',
  size : 'big',
  name : 'Beautiful red',
  count: 2
};

myObject2 = { 
  color: 'blue',
  name : 'Awesome blue',
  count : null
};
```

I need a helper to keep only value i want and which exist :

```
function myHelper() {
   ?????
}


myHelper(myObject1, ['color','size','count']) // => { color: 'red', size : 'big', count:2}
myHelper(myObject2, ['color','size','count']) // => { color: 'blue'}
```

Anyone already created it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the object to entries and filter by:

- Object property (`key`) exists in the desired key list (`props`)
- Value (`val`) is not `null`.

```js
const myObject1 = { 
  color: 'red',
  size : 'big',
  name : 'Beautiful red',
  count: 2
};

const myObject2 = { 
  color: 'blue',
  name : 'Awesome blue',
  count : null
};

function myHelper(obj, props) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key, val]) => props.includes(key) && val != null));
}

console.log(myHelper(myObject1, ['color','size','count']));
console.log(myHelper(myObject2, ['color','size','count']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to optimize this, you can change the "array includes" to a "set has" check via:

```js
const myHelper = (obj, props) => (pSet => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key, val]) => pSet.has(key) && val != null)))
(new Set(props));
```

Comment: Shorter: `const myHelper = (obj, props) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(([key, val]) => props.includes(key) && val != null));`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) we can achieve this

```js
let myObject1 = { 
  color: 'red',
  size : 'big',
  name : 'Beautiful red',
  count: 2
};

let myObject2 = { 
  color: 'blue',
  name : 'Awesome blue',
  count : null
};

const myHelper = (data, keys) => keys.reduce((res, key) => {
  //check if the data is available in the provided object for the given key, if so add it to the result object.
  if (data[key]) {
    res[key] = data[key]
  };
  return res;
}, {})


console.log(myHelper(myObject1, ['color', 'size', 'count']))
console.log(myHelper(myObject2, ['color', 'size', 'count']))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the browser compatibility before you use the `Object.fromEntries` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility)

---

You can do this using `Object.entries` to loop over the object *entries* (`[key, value]` pairs) and `filter` the object *key* `k` if it is in the supplied array (used a `Set` for faster lookup) and the value `v` which are not `null`.

Then pass those *array* of entries to the `Object.fromEntries` and get it as an object:

```js
myObject1 = {
  color: 'red',
  size: 'big',
  name: 'Beautiful red',
  count: 2
};
myObject2 = {
  color: 'blue',
  name: 'Awesome blue',
  count: null
};
function myHelper(obj, arr) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k, v]) => new Set(arr).has(k) && v !== null)
  );
}
console.log(myHelper(myObject1, ['color', 'size', 'count']))
console.log(myHelper(myObject2, ['color', 'size', 'count']))
```

Another option would be to loop over the given keys in the `arr` and `filter` those which are present in the given `obj` and are not `null`.

Then `map` to an array of `[key, value]` pairs and supply that as an argument to the `Object.fromEntries` to output as an object:

```js
myObject1 = {
  color: 'red',
  size: 'big',
  name: 'Beautiful red',
  count: 2
};
myObject2 = {
  color: 'blue',
  name: 'Awesome blue',
  count: null
};
function myHelper(obj, arr) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
   arr.filter(k => obj[k]).map(k => [k, obj[k]])
  );
}
console.log(myHelper(myObject1, ['color', 'size', 'count']))
console.log(myHelper(myObject2, ['color', 'size', 'count']))
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply done using `Array.reduce` for keys.

```js
myObject1 = { 
  color: 'red',
  size : 'big',
  name : 'Beautiful red',
  count: 2
};

myObject2 = { 
  color: 'blue',
  name : 'Awesome blue',
  count : null
};

function myHelper(input, keys) {
  const result = keys.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (input[cur]) {
      acc[cur] = input[cur];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return result;
}


console.log(myHelper(myObject1, ['color','size','count'])); // => { color: 'red', size : 'big', count:2}
console.log(myHelper(myObject2, ['color','size','count'])); // => { color: 'blue'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your key array and build a new object based on your key array. To build the new object from the array, you can map the keys to objects. You can then merge this array of objects into one object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const myObject1 = { color: 'red', size : 'big', name : 'Beautiful red', count: 2 };
const myObject2 = { color: 'blue', name : 'Awesome blue', count : null };

function myHelper(obj, arr) {
  return Object.assign(
    {}, ...arr.map(k => obj[k] != undefined ? {[k]: obj[k]} : {})
  );
}

console.log(myHelper(myObject1, ['color','size','count'])); // => { color: 'red', size : 'big', count:2}
console.log(myHelper(myObject2, ['color','size','count'])); // => { color: 'blue'}
```

By building the object from the keys (rather than filtering out your input object), you save the need to check if the current entry is in your keys array.

Answer (score 0):

**Some of the answers posted here do not explicitly check for `undefined` and `null` thus if the property value is an empty string `""` or `0` they will be filtered as well, which I'm guessing is not what you want.**

You can use `.getOwnPropertyNames` and `.reduce` to filter the properties you want.

```js
function keep(obj = {}, props = []) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((acc, prop) => {
    if (obj[prop] !== undefined && obj[prop] !== null && props.includes(prop)) {
      return { ...acc, [prop]: obj[prop] };
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const cleanedObj = keep({ color: undefined, size: null, count: 0, age: 20 }, [
  "color",
  "size",
  "count",
  "age",
]);

console.log(cleanedObj); // { count: 0, age: 20 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myHelper (sourceObj, [...keys]) {
  let objSubset = Object.entries(sourceObj)
    .filter(([key]) => keys.includes(key))
    .filter(([, value]) => value !== undefined && value !== null)
    .reduce((newObj, [key, val]) => Object.assign(newObj, { [key]: val }), {});
  return objSubset
}

myObject1 = { 
  color: 'red',
  size : 'big',
  name : 'Beautiful red',
  count: 2
};

myObject2 = { 
  color: 'blue',
  name : 'Awesome blue',
  count : null
};

let x = myHelper(myObject1, ['color','size','count']);
let y = myHelper(myObject2, ['color','size','count']);

console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```

The function will not return object with values that are undefined and null but will still return object with `0`, empty string `""` and `Boolean` values.